# Can't upload image from a Reactjs front-end to FastApi

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, fastapi

I have an API endpoint that can processes image. And the API endpoint works fine I checked it properly. But when I try to upload a image file with my Reactjs front-end it doesn't works and gives me a `HTTP 422`  error code.

I am using axios to post the image.
This is my Reactjs upload method. (I am quite to ReactJs.)

```
    onClickHandler = () => {
        const data = new FormData()

        var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/api/image" 

        data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)

        axios.post(host, data, {
            //headers: {
            //    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            //},
            
            // This just for the progress bar
            onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
                this.setState({
                    loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total*100),
                    })
                },
            })
          .then(res => { // then print response status
            toast.success('upload success')
          })
          .catch(err => { // then print response status
            toast.error('upload fail')
          })
    }
```

This the request header from the Swagger UI.
[image]
[image]

This the request header from my Reactjs App.
[image]
[image]

FastApi's response.
[image]

Comment: What is the body of the 422 error? It'll tell you exactly what field is missing or failing validation. What is the FastAPI endpoint definition?

Comment: @MatsLindh 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGXW.png

Comment: According to the error message you're missing an `image` field, but since you're submitting a field named `file`, I'm guessing that's where the confusion is. Make sure the field is named as expected by your backend (i.e. either rename the frontend field to `image` or rename the backend field to `file`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the back-end ```image``` to ```file``` and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the body of the 422 error message FastAPI is expecting a field named `image` to be submitted. In your frontend code you're using the field name `file`. These two need to match, so either change your frontend code to use the name `image` or your backend to expect the name `file` instead.